# How to add a link to answer / question or a comment that opens in new tab?

Tags: discussion, questions

Whenever I add a link to an answer it doesn't gives me any option to open it in new tab `("target='_blank'")` all links open in the same tab.. or may be I don't know the way to do this.

SO, is there anyway to do this??

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You simply don't do that. Only user should decide where to open the link.

Comment: What about the users [who don't know you can do that](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/76179/is-there-research-on-whether-users-know-how-to-open-a-link-in-a-new-tab/76931#76931), and to whom replacing the entire current page is more disruptive than opening a second tab>?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, that would be a different problem that require a different solution, but NOT a solution of automatically forcing new tab on every user regardless if he wants it or not.

Comment: That's not what I suggested. Only suggested that open in the same tab is not optimal in all scenarios either.

Comment: [For example, optional markdown](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266372/165455). I don't think "all new tab all the time" was what this question was about, either; but rather being able to do it in *specific* scenarios.